# node.js async.series is that how it is supposed to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
var async = require('async');

function callbackhandler(err, results) {
    console.log('It came back with this ' + results);
}   

function takes5Seconds(callback) {
    console.log('Starting 5 second task');
    setTimeout( function() { 
        console.log('Just finshed 5 seconds');
        callback(null, 'five');
    }, 5000);
}   

function takes2Seconds(callback) {
    console.log('Starting 2 second task');
    setTimeout( function() { 
        console.log('Just finshed 2 seconds');
        callback(null, 'two');
    }, 2000); 
}   

async.series([takes2Seconds(callbackhandler), 
              takes5Seconds(callbackhandler)], function(err, results){
    console.log('Result of the whole run is ' + results);
})
```

The output looks like below :

```
Starting 2 second task
Starting 5 second task
Just finshed 2 seconds
It came back with this two
Just finshed 5 seconds
It came back with this five
```

I was expecting the takes2Second function to finish completely before the takes5Second starts.
Is that how it is supposed to work. Please let me know.
And the final function never runs. Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not quite. You are executing the functions immediately (as soon as the array is evaluated), which is why they appear to start at the same time.

The callback passed to each of the functions to be executed is internal to the async library. You execute it once your function has completed, passing an error and/or a value. You don't need to define that function yourself.

The final function never runs in your case because the callback function that async needs you to invoke to move on to the next function in the series never actually gets executed (only your `callbackHandler` function gets executed).

Try this instead:

```
async.series([
    takes2Seconds,
    takes5seconds
], function (err, results) {
    // Here, results is an array of the value from each function
    console.log(results); // outputs: ['two', 'five']
});
```

Comment: James, thanks for your clear explanation on what is going on. It works after I made those changes as suggested.Is it possible to pass arguments to these functions?

Comment: On further reading of the docs, looks like i should use async.apply to pass in arguments to functions.

Answer (score 18):

James gave you a good overview of `async.series`. Note that you can setup anonymous functions in the series array and then call your actual functions with parameters

```
var async = require('async')
var param1 = 'foobar'
function withParams(param1, callback) {
  console.log('withParams function called')
  console.log(param1)
  callback()
}
function withoutParams(callback) {
  console.log('withoutParams function called')
  callback()
}
async.series([
  function(callback) {
    withParams(param1, callback)
  },
  withoutParams
], function(err) {
  console.log('all functions complete')
})
```

Comment: Noah, Yes i eventually figured that out. Thanks for posting it anyways.

Answer (score 11):

My preferred way to create the async series is using operational array as follow;

```
var async = require('async'),
    operations = [];

operations.push(takes2Seconds);
operations.push(takes5seconds);

async.series(operations, function (err, results) {
    // results[1]
    // results[2]
});

function takes2Seconds(callback) {
    callback(null, results);
}

function takes5seconds(callback) {
    callback(null, results);
}
```

Comment: It's interesting how you put the .series() function up front. I kinda like that.

Comment: How does `async.series` know that one of the operations has met an error?

Answer (score 7):

```
async.series
    ([  
        function (callback)
        {
            response=wsCall.post(user,url,method,response);
            console.log("one");
            callback();
        }
        ,
        function (callback)
        {
            console.log("two");
            //console.log(response);
            callback();
        }
    ]
    ,
    function(err) 
    {
        console.log('Both a and b are saved now');
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for your answer. This answer would be a lot more useful if it was formatted correctly and explained a little. Not that your help isn't appreciated, but as it stands your answer is likely to be removed because of its quality issues, which doesn't benefit you or anyone else in the community.

Answer (score 4):

In `async.series`,all the functions are executed in series and the consolidated outputs of each function is passed to the final callback. e.g

```
var async = require('async');
async.series([
    function (callback) {
        console.log('First Execute..');
        callback(null, 'userPersonalData');
    },
    function (callback) {
        console.log('Second Execute.. ');
        callback(null, 'userDependentData');
    }
],
function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Output:

```
First Execute..
Second Execute..
['userPersonalData','userDependentData'] //result
```

Comment: How to execute this async series?