# Nodejs run task in sequence

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am new to node.js and I just don't know how to execute a settimeout function before another function,

for example,

```
var async = require('async');
function hello(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('hello');
    },2000);}

function world(){
    console.log("world");
}
async.series([hello,world()]);
```

and the output is always world hello.

Am I using the library right? I dont the question seems trivial but I really have no idea how to force a short task to run after a long one

Comment: Several problems: 1) the expression `world()` executes `world` immediately (this is done *before* `hello` is ever called) 2) `hello` returns *before* the setTimeout completes. For a use of async the `callback`-idiom needs to be used. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969082/node-js-async-series-is-that-how-it-is-supposed-to-work - this explains the problem with `world()` and shows use of the callback parameter.

Comment: So, no: you are using the library wrong (and not explain the behavior correctly). Follow the documentation and search for examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Async` requires you to use `callback`. Follow [this](http://caolan.github.io/async/) link to see some examples. The following code should output `hello world` correctly:

```
var async = require("async");
function hello(callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('hello');
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}

function world(callback) {
    console.log("world");
    callback();
}

async.series([hello, world], function (err, results) {
    // results is an array of the value returned from each function
    // Handling errors here
    if (err)    {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Note that `callback()` was called inside the `setTimeout()` function so that it waits for the `console.log('hello')`.

Answer (score 2):

Use promise

```
function hello(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('hello');
        resolve();
    });
}

function world(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log("world");
      resolve();
    });
}


  hello()
  .then(function(){
     return world()
  })
  .then(function(){
    console.log('both done');
  })
  .catch(function(err){
     console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Can you please upvote and mark my answer as correct if it works for you @ParosKwan

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises instead of callbacks. so your code will be something like below:

```
  var async = require('async');
   function hello(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('hello');
     },2000);}

   function world(){
    console.log("world");
      }
    return Q.fcall(function() {
       hello();
    })
   .then(function(resultOfHelloFunction){
      world();
 });
```

The World() function will only be executed when hello() function is completed its execution.

P.S : I am using **Q** library to **promisify** functions. It's totally fine to use other libraries (such as bluebird) to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Since he was asking about `async` giving him an answer about promises doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score -1):

You can use callback which are the heart of the nodejs.

```
var fun1 = function(cb){
 // long task
 // on done 
 return cb(null, result);
}

var fun2 = function(cb){
 return cb(null, data);
}

fun1(function(err, result){
 if(!err){
   fun2(function(er, data){
    // do here last task

   })
 }
}

// to avoid pyramid of doom use native promises

func1 (){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   // do stuff here
   resolve(data)
 })

}
func2(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(data);
  })
}
```

And then call them using:

```
func1.then((data) => {
 return func2();
})
.then((resule) => {
 //do here stuff when both promises are resolved
})
```

Comment: Answers should be in the context of `async` (which itself uses such callbacks) since it was given. This shows the base of a tower-of-doom and does not explain the issue(s) with the original code.

Comment: Well than you can just use the promises for that!! you won't be even requiring the async lib for doing that or you can also use the yield for making you code more readable.

Comment: thank guys! I shall study more on callback as well, as I am new to nodejs and dont really understand the syntax !