# nodejs: async.series not executing functions in order

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following code, async.series blocks are not executing in sequence.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");
var buffer = new Buffer(10);
var read = "";
var readByt;
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        console.log("test");
        callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        fs.open('c:/ab.txt', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
            fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0, function(err, bytes){
                read = buffer.slice(0, bytes).toString();
                readByt = bytes;        
                console.log("}}}"+read);
                fs.close(fd, function(err){
                    if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    } 
                    console.log("File closed successfully.");           
                })
            })
        })
        callback();
    },
    function (callback){
        console.log("console:"+read);
        console.log("console:"+read.substr(read.length-1));
        console.log("console:"+buffer.slice(0, readByt).toString());
        callback();
    }
],function(){});
```

On executing via command line the buffer printing in the third block happens before the file read operations.

```
c:\>node fr.js
test
console:
console:
console: ?F     p?
}}}c:/log.txt
File closed successfully.
```

How to get these execute in sequence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js async.series is that how it is supposed to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969082/node-js-async-series-is-that-how-it-is-supposed-to-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback is to be called after every async function is complete. In your case, the fs actions are async and completed at a latter time. Before fs actions are completed itself the callback will be called.

Try this, invoke callback inside fs.close.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");
var buffer = new Buffer(10);
var read = "";
var readByt;
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        console.log("test");
        callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        fs.open('c:/ab.txt', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
            fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0, function(err, bytes){
                read = buffer.slice(0, bytes).toString();
                readByt = bytes;        
                console.log("}}}"+read);
                fs.close(fd, function(err){
                    if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    } 
                    console.log("File closed successfully."); 
                    callback();          
                })
            })
        })
    },
    function (callback){
        console.log("console:"+read);
        console.log("console:"+read.substr(read.length-1));
        console.log("console:"+buffer.slice(0, readByt).toString());
        callback();
    }
],function(){});
```

Comment: Thanks @undefined - very well defined answer - works perfect