# Not defined callback using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am trying to use `async` with the aim to make an sync flow.

Following the examples in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969082/node-js-async-series-is-that-how-it-is-supposed-to-work), I did implement the code as follows:

```
function listBuckets(accessToken, prefix, callback) {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b'
    request.get({
        url: url,
        auth: {
            'bearer': accessToken
        }
    }, function(err, res) {
        console.log('API Endpoint:  ' + url);
        console.log('Status Code: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('Response Body:\n' + res.body);
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: res.statusCode,
            body: res.body
        });
    });

}

router.get('/list', oauth2.required, (req, res, next) => {
    var operations = [];
    operations.push(listBuckets(req.user.accessToken, 'myPrefix', callback));
    async.series(operations, function (err, results) {
        const statusCode = results[0].statusCode;
        const body = results[0].body;
    });
});
```

However, I got the following error: `ReferenceError: callback is not defined`.

Could you help me in pointing out what I did wrong?

Comment: Is the error happening on your code, or somewhere else? EDIT: Actually just realized what the problem was, haha

Comment: Can't really get any clearer than that error message... `callback` is not defined in `operations.push(listBuckets(req.user.accessToken, 'myPrefix', callback))`

Comment: Also, `listBuckets` doesn't return anything so `operations.push(listBuckets(...))` isn't going to add anything useful to `operations`

Comment: @Phil Could you help me in pointing out the error with a code correction? It would help me a lot to understand the mistake (I am new with node).

Comment: @Phil I made a simple mistake reading over the code, no need for the snark :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line here:

```
operations.push(listBuckets(req.user.accessToken, 'myPrefix', callback));
```

What this does now, is it calls `listBuckets` with those parameters, then pushes that result to the operations array.

What you want to do is push a *function* to the array instead. [If we look at the docs for the async lib,](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) we'll notice that each of these functions accept a callback param, so we'll do that here: push a function which accepts `callback`, *then* calls the listBuckets function with that callback.

```
operations.push(callback => {
  listBuckets(req.user.accessToken, 'myPrefix', callback)
})
```

Feel free to comment on if and how my explanation can be improved.