# What is the callback argument in async.series?

Tags: node.js, async.js

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        console.log("1");
        callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        console.log("2");
        callback();
    },
], function(err) { 
      console.log("done");
 });
```

I am trying to what is the `callback` argument to the first function in aync series? 
Does the body of the callback need to be provided?

Comment: `callback`  is nothing just the function that is called one when `function 1` complete its works and that that `callback` is passed to another `function 2`

Comment: Does this callback body needs to be provided by caller?

Comment: No, these functions are just passed in argument as a variable.

Comment: But there is the body of that callback provided? Is the second param the body?

Comment: You only have to define the `callback()`  to tell that `function1` works is completed.

Comment: Other than point you mentioned, does callback() have a method-body ?

Comment: I think I got the answer : The callback passed to each of the functions to be executed is internal to the async library. You execute it once your function has completed, passing an error and/or a value. You don't need to define that function yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969082/node-js-async-series-is-that-how-it-is-supposed-to-work

Comment: Callback function is a function that is supposed to be *called back*, hence the name. You shouldn't bother about its body or whatever the function is. Just call it.